# Oat bran flour instead of oat flour

Tags: baking, flour

I bought Oat bran and ground it until flour consistency,
I was wondering, can I use it as flour for baking? (pancakes, bread etc.)
Same question for wheat bran flour as well.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've been substituting ground oat bran for flour for muffins, waffles, and muffins for as long as I can remember, when I am on a diet or a family member is. I have noticed the results to be a tad drier than with regular flour, so i just add a splash (maybe a tablespoon) more liquid (water or milk) depending on what I am doing. I hope that answers your question.